# Is there a way to pass a Window Handle HWND between 2 applications?

Tags: c++, hwnd, window-handles

I have 2 applications, let's say App1 and App2. App1 have a console and a second window where some stuff is displayed.
What i want to do is to be able to see the second window of App1 inside App2(Mirror the window in the second applicaiton)

I read some stuff about window handle but i'm not sure how to use it.Is it enough to just pass the handle of the window to App2?

Are there any other ways to do this mirroring thing?

Comment: Short answer: Yes! The values of `HWND` objects are unique across the system. Longer: What method will you be using to pass the `HWND` between apps?

Comment: To be more precise: At any moment, `HWND` values are unique across the system. But `DestroyWindow(HWND)` may recycle values. So after `App1` closes, its `HWND` may be reused by a new window. See [`IsWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-iswindow) documentation.

Comment: Another way would be for App1 to pass the name and/or class-name of the window to App2 and then App2 can use `FindWindow()` or `FindWindowEx()` to get the handle.

Comment: @AdrianMole, I thought about  Shared Memory Block.

Comment: @SilviuAlexandru `WM_COPYDATA` is very simple to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-copydata